# Meaning of 当分先 (まあ当分先だろうな)

Tags: meaning

Colleague talking about a very expensive business event:

> 1回行ってみたいなーとは思うけど、まあ当分先だろうな。

What does 当分先 mean in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "not in the near (but further into the) future".

Comment: 当分 + 先, just in case.